# Print Cyrillic characters in Genexus report PDF

Tags: genexus

I am printing a character variable in a pdf via the standard Genexus reporting procedure, but when I try to print Cyrillic characters, they are skipped or replaced by question marks. In the record these characters are saved correctly, it is only the printout on pdf that does not show them. Do I need to change anything in the pdfreport.ini file? Or are there other ways?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved setting in my language object (Italian in my case) the codepage as 1251 instead of 1252. In this way it should use windows-1251 encoding that include cyrillic characters. For some reason I had to set the printed variable to Microsoft Sans Serif too